# maven scope runtime doesn't work in my project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-11

This is a springboot project, I use  runtime in my maven dependencies, but it not working
I run the "mvn install" command, stanford-corenlp-models is still packed into the jar package, and the package size becomes very large

jdk: openjdk-11
operating system: macos
maven verison: 3.9.2

main pom.xml

```
  <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
                <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
                <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.4</version>
                <classifier>models</classifier>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

module pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
             <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

I try use provided, it works, stanford-corenlp-models not pack into jar, but project cann't run in idea.

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: How do you expect it to find the library if not packaged in the application?

Comment: Has no specific  error, just package size becomes large.

Comment: I will use mvn -Dloader.path to run, here is my command

Comment: java -cp /home/admin/andl/andl-start-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dloader.path=/home/admin/andl/jars org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as expected.

Dependencies of scope `runtime` are packaged into the final artifact.

Dependencies of scope `provided` are not packaged into the final artifact. It is expected that they are provided by the environment the artifact runs in. If the environment does not provide it, you probably get runtime errors.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `provided` scope, then configure your IDE to add the provided dependencies to the classpath.

[Intellij IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVYYh.png):

> Run -> Edit Configurations.. -> Build and Run -> Modify options ->
> add dependencies with provided scope to classpath